# How to host Java application package similar to Python pypi.org so users can install it via command line and use it?

Tags: python, java, maven, deployment, command-line

I have a Java application which I would like to host on some sort of free hosting website. Later, users can install that application via a command-line tool and use it easily.

While searching I found that its possible to do via https://pypi.org/ for `Python` applications but not sure how to do the same for Java applications.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve something similar for Java application?

Following is the example code I have in my application:

```
public class Operations {

    public static BigDecimal add(final BigDecimal a, final BigDecimal b) {
        return a.add(b);
    }

    public static BigDecimal subtract(final BigDecimal a, final BigDecimal b) {
        return a.subtract(b);
    }

    public static BigDecimal multiply(final BigDecimal a, final BigDecimal b) {
        return a.multiply(b);
    }

    public static BigDecimal divide(final BigDecimal a, final BigDecimal b) {
        return a.divide(b);
    }
}
```

I would like to publish this code or JAR generated by the program into some sort of repository so users can install this application via command line and use it directly in their command line instead of adding dependency and use only in Java IDE.

Please let me know how can I achieve this? I am not sure if this is available or if its possible to achieve. I am posting here to get some options from expert as I am quite new to these things.

Comment: `so users can install this application via command line` by which tool? The question is also is your tools a cli tool or a librarary ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your response. I am looking for something similar to what we have in `Maven Repository` but in the case of `Maven Repository` users need to add the dependency and then use the functionality within that library I am looking for a solution where users can install via command-line tool and run the application directly without needing to add as a dependency to another project.

Comment: My question is not answered. Is your app/tool a cli tool or not ? And which command line tool should do that?

Comment: @khmarbaise It's possible to run Java applications via CLI so I believe the application is a CLI tool. Any normal command-line tool or terminal should do the trick.

Comment: You would like to have a full installer (exe, msi for Windows), DMG for MacOS ?

Answer (score 2):

I know that an Java app can be an CLI tool but I would like to know about your particular post.

Is it a cli tool or not? If it's a CLI tool (Application you have written) it should be published as a complete package (for example as ZIP/tar.gz archive which can be downloaded and executed).

If you need an automatic installation tool you should check for things like install4j, jpackager of the JDK etc.

If it's a library it should be published into central repository (https://central.sonatype.org/) so it can be used as a dependency as usual.

The question keeps: which tool should do the download ? There is no such tool by default ... you can use curl/wget or alike to download but it will not do the installation..or even your own browser to download an artifact...